# HtmlService doPost

Tags: google-apps-script

i am trying to submit a form using doPost but i keep getting the "Unknown macro doPost" error.

The templated Html:

```
<?var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl().replace("exec","dev");?>

...

<form action='<?=url?>' method="post">
  <fieldset>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The script:

```
function doPost(requestInfo){
  Logger.log("Entering doPost()\n");
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h1>404</h1>");

}
```

Any ideas why that's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are geting error because you are posting the data to a wrong URL. Developer and Execution URL do not only differ by dev/exec. Both the URLs are totally different. To test, just hardcode the devloper URL

Comment: For the exec, dev swapping look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280978/href-in-htmlservice).

Comment: And this is another case of taste something before you speak :D.
I tried your suggestion and voila all worked. Thanks again!