# Google apps script html service anchor tags

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

How can you place an anchor tag that references pages in your own project when using the HtmlService to build user interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280978/href-in-htmlservice/11295895#11295895)

The basic technique, copied here:

```
function doGet(requestInfo) {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  if (requestInfo.parameter && requestInfo.parameter['page'] == '2') {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      "This is Page 2. <a href='" + url + "?page=1'>Page 1</a>");
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
     "This is Page 1. <a href='" + url + "?page=2'>Page 2</a>");
}
```