# How to manage hyperlinks in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

If I've created a web app in Google Apps Script using the HtmlService any hyperlinks I include in my template pages during development use the URL structure:
`https://script.google.com/a/macros/[domain]/s/[app dev id]/dev?page=form`

Whereas once the app is deployed the links need to be:

`https://script.google.com/a/macros/[domain]/s/[app exec id]/exec?page=form`

To save me having to change every hyperlink when deploying the web app, what would be the most manageable solution?

Relative hyperlinks don't seem to work and using `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` will only return null if it isn't deployed.

Comment: Are you sure relative links don't work? Are you using them as `href="?page=form"` ? I remember it used to work fine...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280978/href-in-htmlservice

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668119/linking-to-another-html-page-in-google-apps-script

Comment: Create and add [mcve]

Comment: I tested it now: `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` returns either /dev or /exec URL, depending on whether the deployed or development version is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Rubén and soup for your help. This is the solution I was looking for:

## Code.gs

```
function getScriptUrl() {
 var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
 return url;
}
```

## Home.html

```
<?var url = getScriptUrl();?><a href='<?=url?>?page=form'>Go to Form</a>
```

Comment: I've realised that if any template pages include other pages i.e. js, css via:

    function include(filename) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
          .getContent();
   }

Then you need to get the parent page to store the url then use innerHTML to retrieve it.